# How to skip user consent and get access token directly in oAuth 2.0 - C#

Tags: c#, .net, rest, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am having trouble to understand this concept. I am building a console app and I do not need the user consent since the app will do the work for just one user. So I can put the credentials in the code. I have to skip this process to get an access token. But the problem is that the user code returns in the url after the user authorizes the app and to be able to get the access token, I have to use the returned code. But I want to skip this part and get the access token directly using the user's credentials or whatever is needed in the code. It may not seem to be clear enough but I think the ones who are familiar with oAuth 2.0 and dealt with this kind of an issue will understand what I mean. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: OAuth2 supports multiple auth mechanisms (= grant types). You seem to want the password / resource owner grant type which just requires a username and password (which your client must have knowledge of) and transmits to the server which then returns an access token. However, your OAuth2 server must support this grant type.

Comment: Are you sure it's the user that needs to be auth-ed? Have you considered using the client-credentials grant type which doesn't include the user interaction? It's similar, but different, to what you describe.

Comment: Yes I can get an access token using client-credentials but the problem is that the server provides limited access when I use client-credentials. For example, I cannot get the inventory list if I cannot get the user consent and in return get an access token.

Comment: @ckuri Thank you. I think they do not support the resource owner grant. I do not see anything about it in the API documents.